# Variable number of lights in glsl-es shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, lighting

I'm working on a 3d engine, that should work for mobile platforms. Currently I just want to make a prototype that will work on iOS and use forward rendering. In the engine a scene can have a variable number of lights of different types (directional, spot etc). When rendering, for each object (mesh) an array of lights that affect this object is constructed. The array will always have 1 or more elements. I can pack the light source information into 1D texture and pass to the shader. The number of lights can be put into this texture or passed as a separate uniform (I did not try it yet, but these are my thoughts after googling).

The problem is that not all glsl-es implementation support `for` loops with variable limits. So I can't write a shader that will loop through light sources and expect it to work on a wide range on platforms. **Are there any technics to support variable number of lights in a shader if `for` loops with variable limits are not supported?**

**The idea I have:**
Implement some preprocessing of shader source to unroll loops manually for different number of lights.
So in that case if I would render all objects with one type of shader and if the number of lights limits are 1 to 3, I will end-up having 3 different shaders (generated automatically) for 1, 2 and 3 lights.
**Is it a good idea?**

Comment: i think shader variations is the way to go here... i know tri-ace ended up with something like 60,000 shaders for star ocean 4: http://www.slideshare.net/DAMSIGNUP/so4-flexible-shadermanagmentandpostprocessing

Comment: It really has nothing to do with your loop control being a variable; you cannot implement a loop without that. The problem you are having is that the actual test expression used for the loop index variable is non-const. Not all implementations are guaranteed to support that in ES 2.0. One thing you could consider is always executing 3 iterations of your loop, but multiplying the loop's result on each iteration by an array of booleans. If you only wanted the result from light 0, then this array would look like { 1, 0, 0 }. It is a hack at best, but it keeps things sort of simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the source code for a shader consists of strings that you pass in at runtime, there's nothing stopping you from building the source code dynamically, depending on the number of lights, or any other parameters that control what kind of shader you need.

If you're using a setup where the shader code is in separate text files, and you want to keep it that way, you can take advantage of the fact that you can use preprocessor directives in shader code. Say you use `LIGHT_COUNT` for the number of lights in your shader code. Then when compiling the shader code, you prepend it with a definition for the count you need, for example:

```
#define LIGHT_COUNT 4
```

Since `glShaderSource()` takes an array of strings, you don't even need any string operations to connect this to the shader code your read from the file. You simply pass it in as an additional string to `glShaderSource()`.

Shader compilation is fairly expensive, so you'll probably want to cache the shader program for each light count.

Another option is what Andon suggested in a comment. You can write the shader for the upper limit of the light count you need, and then pass in uniforms that serve as multipliers for each light source. For the lights you don't need, you set the multiplier to 0. That's not very efficient since you're doing extra calculations for light sources you don't need, but it's simple, and might be fine if it meets your performance requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Preprocessing is exactly what I wanted to do, but since I'm a new to openGL, I was not sure it is a good idea